# Signup using HybridIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, hybridauth

I am creating a new application in which I want to let the user choose between creating an account from the scratch or let him sign up using his social networking credentials.

I am using Tank auth for registering right now and found that hybridigniter would be better for social integration. I need help in figuring out how I would be able to sign up a new user without social sites using only hibridginter.

Answer (score 0):

A3M (https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M) is doing exactly what you want.

A3M v2 is also using Hybrid Auth. I would recommend giving it a look.